# Streaming remote files into file objects

Tags: java, sshj

If anyone knows a quick way how to get a remote file directly streaming into a file object, so it isn't necessary to store the file temporary on a computer it would be greatly appreciated!
Until now I copy the file from a remote ios-device as follows (using net.schmizz.sshj):

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(fingerprint);
ssh.connect(ip);

try {
    ssh.authPassword("username", "userpassword".toCharArray());
    ssh.newSCPFileTransfer().download(fileRemote, new FileSystemFile(fileLocal));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

**If there's anyone who's interested in the code of the solution:**

As Nutlike mentioned in his answer it's better to use `InMemoryDestFile`.
So create the following class:

```
class MyInMemoryDestFile extends InMemoryDestFile {
    public ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public ByteArrayOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return this.outputStream;
    }
}
```

... in your method where you perform the download operation create an instance of your new class:

```
MyInMemoryDestFile a = new StreamingInMemoryDestFile();
```

and access the outputstream:

```
ssh.newSCPFileTransfer().download(remoteFile, a);
a.getOutputStream().toByteArray();
```

best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it not be sufficient to use [InMemoryDestFile](http://static.javadoc.io/com.hierynomus/sshj/0.22.0/net/schmizz/sshj/xfer/InMemoryDestFile.html) instead of [FileSystemFile](http://static.javadoc.io/com.hierynomus/sshj/0.22.0/net/schmizz/sshj/xfer/FileSystemFile.html)?

Edit: … and then use [*getOutputStream()*](http://static.javadoc.io/com.hierynomus/sshj/0.22.0/net/schmizz/sshj/xfer/LocalDestFile.html#getOutputStream%28%29) to access the 'file' …